# Next.js cannot find module loader.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, next.js

This is the error is occurring when I try to run a `npm run dev`.

I don't understand what's happening and I tried these: deleting `package-lock.json`, deleting `node_modules`, reinstalling npm, but nothing works.

```
PS D:\Users\user\Documents\Projects\NLW#5\podcastrnext> npm run dev

> podcastrnext@0.1.0 dev D:\Users\user\Documents\Projects\NLW#5\podcastrnext
> next dev

ready - started server on 0.0.0.0:3000, url: http://localhost:3000
info  - Using webpack 5. Reason: no next.config.js https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/webpack5
error - ../../NLW#5/podcastrnext/node_modules/next/dist/client/dev/amp-dev.js
Error: Cannot find module 'D:\Users\user\Documents\Projects\NLW#5\podcastrnext\node_modules\@next\react-refresh-utils\loader.js'
Require stack:
- D:\Users\user\Documents\Projects\NLW#5\podcastrnext\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\webpack\bundle5.js
- D:\Users\user\Documents\Projects\NLW#5\podcastrnext\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\webpack\webpack.js
- D:\Users\user\Documents\Projects\NLW#5\podcastrnext\node_modules\next\dist\next-server\server\config-utils-worker.js
- D:\Users\user\Documents\Projects\NLW#5\podcastrnext\node_modules\next\dist\next-server\server\config-utils.js
- D:\Users\user\Documents\Projects\NLW#5\podcastrnext\node_modules\next\dist\next-server\server\config.js
- D:\Users\user\Documents\Projects\NLW#5\podcastrnext\node_modules\next\dist\server\next.js
- D:\Users\user\Documents\Projects\NLW#5\podcastrnext\node_modules\next\dist\server\lib\start-server.js
- D:\Users\user\Documents\Projects\NLW#5\podcastrnext\node_modules\next\dist\cli\next-dev.js
- D:\Users\user\Documents\Projects\NLW#5\podcastrnext\node_modules\next\dist\bin\next
<i> [webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy/webpack.FileSystemInfo] Node.js doesn't offer a (nice) way to introspect the ESM dependency graph yet.
<i> Until a full solution is available webpack uses an experimental ESM tracking based on parsing.
<i> As best effort webpack parses the ESM files to guess dependencies. But this can lead to expensive and incorrect tracking.
<i> [webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy/webpack.FileSystemInfo] Node.js doesn't offer a (nice) way to introspect the ESM dependency graph yet.
<i> Until a full solution is available webpack uses an experimental ESM tracking based on parsing.
<i> As best effort webpack parses the ESM files to guess dependencies. But this can lead to expensive and incorrect tracking.
```

Answer (score 18):

I had this same issue, removing the "#" from the project path worked just fine.

Comment: Great! Thanks for helping us, Luis!

Comment: That fixed it for me, thanks!

Answer (score 10):

I was able to resolve my problem, I don't know exactly what it was, but I might have a clue.

I was trying to run in this folder **"D:\Users\user\Documents\Projects\NLW#5\podcastrnext"** and didn't work. Than I tried changing to another folder, this is the folder that I used **"D:\Users\user\Documents\Projects\podcastr"** and this time worked.

I believe the problem was in the special character "#", somehow the program got lost with it.

Comment: Helps me. Special characters on directory path causing this problem.
Thank you!

Comment: I had a hyphen in my directory path, removing it worked for me!

Answer (score 2):

In file **next.config.js** insert in module.exports:

webpack5: false

Comment: You are a Life-saver !

Comment: Tried this but got "Webpack 4 is no longer supported in Next.js. Please upgrade to webpack 5 by removing "webpack5: false" from next.config.js." ... I am running Next version 12.1.5

Answer (score 0):

I had a hyphen in my root directory for my Next.js project, changing my root folder from `my-app` to just `myapp` fixed the issue.